# Can I install ubuntu to a hard drive via sd card?

Tags: hard-drive

I don't have a usb drive or cd, all I have is a sd card, could I wipe my hard drive and install ubuntu with some sort of file I can put onto an sd card? I don't really know how any of this works please help

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Go to the download link for ubuntu and download the ISO. If you are on windows, use [Win32 Disk Imager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) to write the ISO to the SD card. If you are on Mac, use [Etcher](https://etcher.io/). When it is finished writing to the card put it in the computer you are installing to and open the boot menu when you turn it on (probably Esc, F2, F10 or F12) and select the SD card and hit enter. That should start Ubuntu booting and you can install from there.

Comment: True in general, but some BIOS won't boot on the built-in card reader. It should still be possible to boot with the SD card in an external USB card reader.